# C preprocessor vs. C compiler

Tags: c, makefile

If I tell the C preprocessor to #include a file and use CPPFLAGS to help find the needed file, then the file is included already, right?  What, if any, use is telling the C compiler about the same include directory with CFLAGS?

Comment: @Duracell: No, that's `CXXFLAGS`. `CPPFLAGS` is for the C PreProcessor.

Comment: @Thoams The clarification you made is important. There are numerous misleading references to CPPFLAGS vs. CXXFLAGS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any use.

The [implicit make rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) indicates that `CFLAGS` is only used when compiling C programs (from .c to .o). The value of `CPPFLAGS` is also added to the compiler command line.

`CPPFLAGS` is also used in the following rules:

- Compiling C++ programs
- Compiling Fortran and Ratfor programs
- Preprocessing Fortran and Ratfor programs
- Assembling and preprocessing assembler programs
- Making Lint Libraries from C, Yacc, or Lex programs

Since `CPPFLAGS` is used in every case where `CFLAGS` is used, there seems to be no point in adding `-I` directives to `CFLAGS` that are already in `CPPFLAGS`.

Of course, if your Makefile has custom rules that pass `CFLAGS` to the compiler, but omit `CPPFLAGS`, it's a different story.

Comment: Order could be though make a difference but at least for GNU make default rules, CLFAGS is added after CPPFLAGS and so you can't use it to change the relative order of two directories (note that if you depend on that, you already are in a tigh situation).

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I guess what I'm left wondering is what the C compiler does with include paths itself.  Say, for the moment, that the compiler does **NOT** see CPPFLAGS.  In that case, would it barf without knowing the needed include path?  Why?  As far as I see, the preprocessor has already resolved the path and included the needed include file.

Comment: Yeah, but most of the time, the `cc` program does both preprocessing *and* compiling. There's no separate program for either.

Comment: cpp is most certainly separate from cc.  The confusion arises because it is rarely invoked directly as cc usually takes care of it.   Think of cpp as a language templater, it does not understand nor care about the underlying source code generated.